# Marshalling SAFEARRAY of IUnknown to C#

Tags: c#, com-interop

I have a COM interface from a thirdparty which has a function

```
STDMETHOD(GetProperties)(THIS_ /*[in]*/IUnknown* pObject, /*[out, retval]*/VARIANT *pPropertyArray)
```

The second parameter is a SAFEARRAY of IUnknowns.

I want to use this interface in C# and tried marshalling this as follows.

```
[Guid("61D0A8E3-C792-4956-8E96-59​4315B95902")]
[InterfaceTypeAttribute(ComInterfaceType.InterfaceIsIUnknown)]
[ComVisible(true)]
public interface IPropertySource
{
    void GetProperties([In, MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.IUnknown)]Object objectSource,
        [In, Out, MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.SafeArray, SafeArraySubType = VarEnum.VT_UNKNOWN)] object[] properties);
};
```

But the second parameter wasnt marshalled properly.

Could anyone help me with the correct marshalling please?

Regards,
Ram

Comment: The second argument is *not* a safe array.  There's an extra level of indirection, it is a variant that refers to a safe array.  Use `out object` instead.  The calling code then has to cast the returned object to an array.

Comment: Thanks Hans. I had tried that too earlier. But then it didn't work because inside my implementation I was creating an array of object. But when I created an array of actual COM object, I was able to make it work. :-)